# How to implement a generics interface without specific types?

Tags: c#, generics

Given an interface like this:

```
public interface Transformer<TSource, TResult> {
    TResult Transform(TSource original);
}
```

I want to provide a simple "no-op" implementation of that interface for cases where no transformation is needed, which would just return the original object itself. In that case, `TSource` and `TResult` would be the same.

Being an old Java dude who's still learning C#, my first though was just this:

```
public class NoopTransformer : Transformer<object, object> {
    public override object Transform(object original) {
        return original;
    }
}
```

That compiles but I can't practically use it anywhere that just expects a `Transformer`. If I try, I get compile errors that say `NoopTransformer` can't be used as a `Transformer<TSource, TResult>`

What I long for is Java's wildcards or willingness to treat `Object` as an acceptable type parameter for any object. Is there really no equivalent in C#?

---

Then I thought this would work:

```
public class NoopTransformer<TSource> : Transformer<TSource, TSource> {
    public override TSource Transform(TSource original) {
        return entity;
    }
}
```

That doesn't work in any place that expects a `Transformer<TSource, TResult>`, like this:

```
public class Controller<TEntity, TResult> {
    private Transformer<TEntity, TResult> transformer;

    public Controller() : this(new NoopTransformer<TEntity>()) // error on this line
        { }

    public Controller(Transformer<TEntity, TResult> transformer) {
        this.transformer = transformer;
    }
}
```

That fails to compile, saying,

- Cannot convert from `NoopTransformer<TEntity>` to `Transformer<TSource, TResult>`
- Type TEntity doesn't match the expected type TResult.
- Argument type `NoopTransformer<TEntity>` is not assignable to parameter type `Transformer<TEntity, TResult>`

(even though it seems obvious that my impl satisfies that contract - the fact that `TSource` and `TResult` are the same shouldn't matter).

---

Finally, grasping at straws, I tried this:

```
public class NoopTransformer<TSource, TResult> : Transformer<TSource, TResult>
    where TResult : TSource
{
    public override TResult Transform(TSource original) {
        return (TResult)entity;
    }
}
```

But of course that doesn't work because where I want to use this, there is no constraint that says `TResult` must extend `TSource`.

---

The context is that I have another class that has the same `TSource` and `TResult` type parameters, and can accept a `Transformer` in its constructor. But the transformer is optional in that class; I want to use `NoopTransformer` in cases where the client doesn't specify a more specific `Transformer`.

In Java this is trivial, in fact with a couple of different ways to solve it (using type wildcards, `extends`, etc). I realize that Java is more lenient (due to its use of type erasure), and so is inherently more flexible since there are no type parameters at runtime. But it seems that the C# compiler is being unnecessarily strict (and maybe a little dumb).

How can I achieve my goal of having a useful default for the interface?

Comment: Why would you expect a `Transformer<TSource, TSource>` to be compatible with `Transformer<TSource, TResult>`? Where does the `TResult` parameter come from? This obviously shouldn't hold in general.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "but again won't work in any place that expects a `Transformer<TSource, TResult>`". It will if you specify the right type argument. That second solution looks the right one to me, so I suggest you expand that part of the question with a concrete example of what's going wrong.

Comment: Some sample that actually shows what fails would help... So far standard `return (TResult)(object)entity;` would let you make code without any constraints to compile but move error to run-time.

Comment: I added an example of how I'm trying to use the `NoopTransformer` in the second solution, along with the compilation error message.

Comment: public Controller(Transformer<TEntity, TResult> transformer) {
        this.transformer = transformer;
    }  specifies the type of the transformer.  The NoopTransformer  is a Transformer<TEntity, TEntity>  this does not match.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're looking for. A transformer can only be no-op if TSource and TResult are the same (thus `NoopTransformer<TSource> : Transformer<TSource, TSource>` makes sense), and such a transformer obviously can't be used in a context when TSource and TResult are unrelated because that would violate type safety.

Comment: @MichaelLiu, let me try to state it in non-code terms: The general case is that I need a transformer interface for any arbitrary 2 types, source and result. In some cases, those two types can actually be the same type. I want that second scenario to be used if no other transformer implementation is specified, and I want to write a general-pupose transformer for that case.

Comment: Consider this line: `public Controller() : this(new NoopTransformer<TEntity>()) // error on this line`. What do you want the transformer to do if TEntity and TResult aren't the same?

Comment: I'd expect a runtime exception in that scenario, but it doesn't really matter because that would be nonsensical and a programming or configuration mistake.

Comment: It seems that some of you are questioning the requirement/desire, which as I'm sure you can guess is not what I come to SO for. I've already stated that none of the solution ideas I have tried will even compile; I've also stated my need in non-code terms. So if my solutions are barking up the wrong tree, give me some other ones, please. Or ask for more clarification in the question. Just don't keep saying, "your requirement is invalid."

Comment: Please add more code as to how you are planning to use`Transformer` derived classes including `NoopTransformer`. The intent of the code is _not clear at all_ at this point making it difficult to answer effectively.

Comment: I think the root of the problem is that `C#` treats each generic declaration as a different type (`List<int>` is different from `List<string>`),  **and** you are qualifying these types with a return type `TResult` which is not part of method signatures to trigger overloading.

Comment: Can't you just use `Func<TSource,TResult>` and `Fun<T, T> noop = (x)=>x`?

Comment: A function doesn't really suite the needs, in general (outside the scope of this "default" "no-op" implementation). Besides, wouldn't a function like that still have the same problem with types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is correct to reject

```
public Controller() : this(new NoopTransformer<TEntity>())
```

since a `Transformer<TEntity, TEntity>` is not compatible with `Transformer<TEntity, TResult>` since `TEntity` and `TResult` are not guaranteed to be the same e.g.

```
var c = new Controller<string, int>();
```

You can maintain static safety by creating a factory method for constructing a `Controller` instance where `TEntity` and `TResult` are the same:

```
public static class Controller
{
    public static Controller<TEntity, TEntity> Create<TEntity>()
    {
        return new Controller<TEntity, TEntity>(new IdentityTransformer<TEntity>());
    }
}
```

if for some reason you cannot adopt this approach you will have to rely on casting at runtime:

```
public class CastingTransformer<TSource, TResult> : Transformer<TSource, TResult>
{
    public TResult Transform(TSource original)
    {
        return (TResult)(object)original;
    }
}

public Controller() : this(new CastingTransformer<TEntity, TResult>()) { }
```

Comment: I had considered exploring if a factory method would help, but I'm in the context of Unity so the controllers are created by the DI/IoC container. Being new to .Net and Unity I'm not sure how to get it to use the method instead of a constructor (or if that's even possible). I wish I had a "Unity for Java Spring Developers" guide :-)

Comment: @E-Riz When your register your type with Unity you can pass in a factory method as one of the parameters to the registration. The parameter to the registration will be a `new InjectionFactory(() => ...)`

Comment: I've not see the syntax like `(TResult)(object)original` - is there a name for that? "Double cast" or something? Or some reference docs to read?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
public interface Transformer<TSource, TResult>
{
    TResult Transform(TSource original);
}

public class NoopTransformer<TSource, TResult> : Transformer<TSource, TResult> where TResult : class
{
    public TResult Transform(TSource original)
    {
        return original as TResult;
    }
}

public class Controller<TEntity, TResult> where TResult : class
{
    private Transformer<TEntity, TResult> transformer;

    public Controller() : this(new NoopTransformer<TEntity, TResult>())
    { }

    public Controller(Transformer<TEntity, TResult> transformer)
    {
        this.transformer = transformer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this reflects my intention (mostly). The part I was missing was the constraint on TResult as extending `class`.

Comment: I think it should work, as long as TResult is a class and not an interface.

Comment: But if you declare `new Controller<string,int>()` it will fail spectacularly. There has to be something common or a connection between `TSource` and `TResult` for this to work.

Comment: @ja72: In my situation such a declaration, if used in conjunction with the no-arg constructor, would be nonsensical and I'd be happy that it "fails spectacularly." If an instance of Controller is needed with different types, the other constructor should be used.

Comment: @E-Riz The way I see it, you are just creating a shortcut, creating one controller with two different functionalities, instead of having two different controllers. So, perhaps a better option would be to create two separate interfaces and separate implementations. Is that an option for you? But if you want to stick with 1 interface, and given your comment to ja72, the code I posted should do the trick for you.

Comment: It's not the Controller that has different functionality, its the Transformers. But your point is still interesting; however, I don't see how I could define two different Transformer interfaces that the Controller can use interchangeably.  In any case, either of these answers solves the problem satisfactorily - I accepted the other one only because it fails at runtime if TSource and TResult are not the same, while this solution simply returns null.

Comment: I would go with 2 generic controllers. One with no params in the ctor and no need for a transformer, because it only ever cares about TEntity, and its functionality is only concerned with 1 type. The other one actually needs to deal with two types, needs a transformer, and looks like the one you defined (minus parameterless ctor). I'm speculating here because I don't have more insight in your code and the exact requirement, but the fact you want 1 controller which behaves differently in different scenarios, makes me think those concerns should be separated. But, if it works for you - cool.